# Laravel Eloquent relationship returning null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I seem to be having issues with my Eloquent relationships.  I have a couple of tables to demonstrate

```
Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->integer('propertyid')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->longText('description')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('garden')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('parking')->nullable();
});

Schema::create('address', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('propertyid')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('street')->nullable();

    $table->foreign('propertyid')
        ->references('propertyid')
        ->on('properties')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Removed a lot of columns to cut down on code.  The relationships are pretty straight forward, within Property.php I define the relationship to address, using the foreign key name.

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'propertyid');
}
```

And then in Address.php I do the inverse

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class, 'propertyid');
}
```

When I populate my database, I can go into the address table, click on the propertyid, and it takes me to the correct property, so it seems to be set up correctly.  However, in my Controller, if I do

```
$properties = Property::with('address')->paginate(6);
```

And I output this using `dd`, the relations output returns null

```
#relations: array:6 [
    "address" => null
]
```

Why does this not pick up the relationship?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mention `localkey` as well  in `hasOne` relation.Looks like mapping between two table columns are `propertyid` not `id` as per migration

```
   $table->foreign('propertyid')
        ->references('propertyid')
```

So realtionship should be

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'propertyid','propertyid');
}
```

Also need yo change belongsTo relationship as well

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class, 'propertyid', 'propertyid');
}
```